# uwp ListView update

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

Currently uwp is a student who is doing a private project. Because there is no textbook, uwp youtube and google get the data and learn one by one.
Currently there is a bad part of writing code.

It is said to create a program that will print the bitcoin chart in real time.
Now I have completed the data output chart from the listview, but I do not know how to update it in real time.

What should I do if the chart is displaying information in real time?

XAML

```
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <!--코인-->
                        <TextBlock FontSize="12dp" Width="110dp" Text="{Binding Coin_Name}"></TextBlock>

                        <!--현재가-->
                        <TextBlock FontSize="12dp" Width="120dp" Text="{Binding Last}"></TextBlock>

                        <!--매수가-->
                        <TextBlock FontSize="12dp" Width="120dp" Text="{Binding Bid}"></TextBlock>

                        <!--매도가-->
                        <TextBlock FontSize="12dp" Width="120dp" Text="{Binding Ask}"></TextBlock>

                        <!--최저가 (24시기준)-->
                        <TextBlock FontSize="12dp" Width="160dp" Text="{Binding Low}"></TextBlock>

                        <!--최고가 (24시기준)-->
                        <TextBlock FontSize="12dp" Width="150dp" Text="{Binding High}"></TextBlock>

                        <!--변동 금액-->
                        <TextBlock FontSize="12dp" Width="180dp" Text="{Binding Change}"></TextBlock>

                        <!--변동률-->
                        <TextBlock FontSize="12dp" Width="140dp" Text="{Binding ChangePercent}"></TextBlock>

                        <!--거래량-->
                        <TextBlock FontSize="12dp" Text="{Binding Volume}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

C#
     async void getListData()
        {

```
        while (true)
        {
            Storage.ItemsSource = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                string url = "https://api.korbit.co.kr/v1/ticker/detailed?currency_pair=" + Coins[i];


                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

                string response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                // json 데이터 가져오기
                var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(response);

                Debug.WriteLine("Log : " + data.last);
                Time = long.Parse(data.timestamp.ToString());

                DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(Time);
                DateTime dateTime = dateTimeOffset.UtcDateTime.ToLocalTime();

                Time_Block.Text = dateTime.ToString();


                Price.Add(new Price_List
                {
                    Coin_Name = Coin_List[i],
                    Last = data.last,
                    Bid = data.bid,
                    Ask = data.ask,
                    High = data.high,
                    Low = data.low,
                    Change = data.change,
                    ChangePercent = data.changePercent,
                    Volume = data.volume
                });
            }
            //ListInvest_Chart 에  Pirce 값을 넣음
            ListInvest_Chart.ItemsSource = Price;
            Storage.ItemsSource = Price;

            await Task.Delay(5000);                
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you talking about learning source of microsoft , there is already huge source provided by microsoft better than any one else e.g mva,Channel 9 etc. In this website you will definitely found a video about  INotifyChange which will help you to update data and also a simple method with time dispatcher

Comment: Please follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth) and [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlBind) to narrow your issue.